# Custom delegate not calling UITableViewController method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a custom UIButton class like below :

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class FriendButton;
@protocol LongPressedButtonDelegate
- (void)buttonIsLongPressed:(FriendButton *)button;
@end

@interface FriendButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<LongPressedButtonDelegate > delegate;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation FriendButton




//this is called from the interface builder
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder];
    NSLog(@"init called");
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

    return self;

}

-(void)longPress:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"long press");
    [self.delegate buttonIsLongPressed:self];
}

@end
```

My buttons are set up in the interface builder, they are contained in a UITableView cell. In my UITableViewController I have :

```
-(void)buttonIsLongPressed:(FriendButton *)button {

    NSLog(@"Delegate method!");

}
```

and it controller conforms to  protocol. The long press gesture works but the delegate method is not being called. I'm not sure why it's not working. Is it because I have to set each buttons delegate to the UITableViewController? If so how would I do that? The buttons are set up in the interface builder.

Comment: You haven't linked LongPressedButtonDelegate to UITableViewController. so it delegate is nil

Comment: You would have to create an outlet of some sort and do longPressButtonOutlet.delete = self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your UIButton property this way

```
@interface FriendButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet id<LongPressedButtonDelegate > delegate;
@end
```

Then go to Interface Builder and right click on UIButton and you will see delegate link this delegate to UITableViewController. It should work

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation in your UITableViewController you will need to do something like:

```
cell.button.delegate = self;
```

Edit: This is if you want to do it programmatically. Refer to the answers around IBOutlets if you want to do it in your storyboard.